Unable to write to Program Files even with requireAdministrator
I'm creating a custom WPF .NET 8 installer for an app we're deploying. The app itself won't require admin rights to run, but the installer needs permission to write to Program Files.
According to lots¹ of posts I found in SO as well as CodeProject, I should be able to access the protected folder by setting <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> on an app.manifest file on my project.
I have done so, and yet, when trying to create files there, I get an "Access Denied" error. As reference, this is the code I'm running:
var embeddedFiles = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
foreach (string embeddedFile in embeddedFiles)
{
    using var fileStream = new FileStream(
        Path.Combine(InstallationDirectory,
            embeddedFile.Split($"{projectName}.InstallFiles.")[0]), FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.Write);
    using var file = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedFile);
    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}

A difference I noticed was that in all of the examples and articles I found, the aim was to copy an existing file from another place to Program Files, while I'm using a FileStream to copy a file from an embedded resource to the protected folder. I don't know if that makes any difference, but it's worth noting.
I also found something interesting. I've created a simple console app that access a file from a folder inside ProgramFiles and copies it to the same folder, with a different name:
Console.WriteLine("I'll try to duplicate a file now...");
try
{
    var embeddedFiles = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
    using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Program Files\OpenMPT\License.txt", FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.Write);
    using var file = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedFiles[0]);
    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    Console.WriteLine("Alas, I couldn't do it...");
    return;
}
Console.WriteLine("Egad! I did it!");

It worked flawlessly.

¹ I've found, so far, these:

C# Can't Access System Files even with administrator privileges
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/798662/How-can-I-write-to-program-files-x-folder
Access to “Program Files” folder needed
Access Program Files folder from users group using .NET code


For clarity's sake, you are getting the UAC prompt and clicking "Yes" on it right?

Even with administrator access, any resource can be blocked access even by administrators if ACLs says so.  But most likely is that the program is not even getting admin rights in the first place. The requireAdministrator manifest don't ensures that.

@Logarr Yes. And I totally understand where the question is coming from...

@Alejandro, the UAC dialog does pop by, and the executable file has the UAC shield on it. Are there any other settings I can try changing?

@ArturS. Great, now check the permissions of the folder you're trying to write to. Make sure the administrators group have write access.

Another possibility is that your system has an antivirus or other similar "security" software that is blocking it. Try disabling them if you really have write access.

Alright, I found the issue. I'll be posting it as an answer shortly, but the gist of it is that .NET mislabels the error as an unauthorised access, however the cause of it is an invalid destination filename. I feel kinda ashamed for not noticing this beforehand...

@ArturS. is it that the filename is invalid, or just incorrect?

The way I was extracting the filename (Split()[0]) was actually returning string.Empty.
